# Cannot load an play video on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I try to play a video on my Cordova app and cannot make it load on the device. The video is located on /www . Cordova version is 6.3.0.

```
<video src="vid.mp4" webkit-playsinline width="200" height="200"></video>
```

I cannot manage to find the path in order to make the video load. When I inspect the source, the video doesn't load...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to make it work using a path like this :

```
<video src="./vid.mp4" webkit-playsinline width="200" height="200"></video>
```

Add the "./" before name of file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin

cordova plugin add https://github.com/ednasgoldfishuk/VideoThumbnail.git
with the code

`cordova.plugins.videoPlayer.play("file:///android_asset/www/***/your_video.mp4");`

Comment: The question say its on iOS.

Comment: this plugin is compatible with iOS